# How to use jquery in react js

Tags: jquery, reactjs, typescript

This is my code.

```
import React from 'react';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
    root: {}
});

function index() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
       <div className={classes.root}>
          <div id="data">Hello!</div>
       </div>
    );
}
```

How can I use jquery in this code?
I want to extract "Hello!" by using jquery.
Please help me.

Comment: What is the reason that you would like to use jQuery in React? What would you like to achieve?

Comment: React is meant to replace jQuery if you use React properly, you simple can have `Hello` in a variable and print inside the `div` and use that variable anywhere you want.